# Add new field on new trace file in NS2

Tags: ns2

I want to modify the new trace file for aodv. In AODV::rt_resolve(Packet *p) , I create an variable `teste` to get 0 or 1 depend an condition.

Ho to write the `teste` variable  to the trace file?

Comment: May be an entry to `tcl/lib/ns-[file].tcl : `$ cd tcl/lib/ && grep -in trace *

Comment: Thanks for answer. Directory does not exist. What I need is that a varivavel created and declared inside the AODV.H is accessible within the CMU_TRACE.cc which is the file that does the trace

Comment: »» Directory does not exist «« : What do you mean ? Which folder is non existing ?

Comment: cd tcl/lib/ && grep -in trace.. trace file are stored in folder trace